# Como redirecionar site para outra pasta no nivel do public_html usando htaccess

Tags: htaccess, redirecionamento

Tenho um site criado e os arquivos estão na pasta public_html. Criamos um novo na pasta 2018 que está no mesmo nível hierárquico da public_html

Como posso fazer para quando acessar o dominio.com.br, ele acesse a pasta 2018 e não a public_html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Felizmente**, por segurança, você não pode redirecionar por meio de `.htaccess` a um diretório de nível superior ao de seu *document root*. Por conseqüência, um diretório no mesmo nível não pode ser acessado.

Existem, claro, alternativas para solucionar seu problema. Cito duas:

---

### Primeiro

Você pode colocar o diretório `2018` dentro do diretório `public_html`. Com uma configuração do `.htaccess` (vide abaixo), você pode fazer o site apontar para o conteúdo deste sub-diretório `2018`. Veja:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^exemplo\.com\.br$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.exemplo\.com\.br$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !nome_diretorio/
RewriteRule (.*) /nome_diretorio/$1 [L]
```

Basta trocar `exemplo\.com\.br` pelo domínio desejado. Troque também `nome_diretorio` pelo diretório do sítio reformulado - neste caso, `2018`.

### Segundo

Você pode pedir para o controlador do host que permita mais um diretório para seu site. Isso é improvável e pouco prático para ambos.

Comment: entendi, vou jogar dentro do public então, valeu!